# How to load a csv file into AWS Aurora Database (Relationional database) usign AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue, amazon-aurora

I have a csv file which will be present (daily new file) in S3 bucket. From here I am trying to use AWS Glue to extract, transform & load in AWS Aurora Database. Aurora DB is designed as a normalized relational database, I have to load the csv into this relational database with information mapped between multiple tables.

Steps that I am trying:
1) Modify the python script to perform the load operation.

Wanted to know if there is any other way to achieve this load operation?

Answer (score 4):

RDS Aurora provides a feature built-in where in you can load data from a CSV file residing in a S3 bucket using "LOAD DATA FROM S3 into TABLE".  You need to add appropriate IAM roles, and configure it in the Aurora parameter groups.

We are using this feature for the past one year, and its working fine.  You can also do the reverse as well, like unload data from a table into a S3 bucket.  Can you please check the following link for more information and testing.  Hope I got your question correct?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html

Thanks,

Yuva

Comment: where to write this statement LOAD DATA FROM S3  , in lambda function

Comment: Not from lambda, as lambda is not meant for data loading, but best for orchestration purposes.  The OP was using AWS Glue, and LOAD DATA FROM S3 would be a pyspark code within the AWS Glue services..Refer here for code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59563663/how-to-write-the-etl-job-to-transfer-the-mysql-database-table-to-another-mysql-r/59574016?noredirect=1#comment105316409_59574016