# How To write the ETL job to transfer the mysql database table to another mysql rds database

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

I am new to AWS. I want to write the ETL script using AWS Glue to transfer the data from one mysql database to another RDS mysql database .

Please suggest me to how to do this job using AWS glue

Thanks

Comment: is the mysql database residing on-prem? Does it have a public IP to connect from AWS Glue?

Comment: Both the Mysql database are in same AWS RDS account

Comment: @SomnathRokade are you planning to apply some transformations before writing the data to new database? And what's the size of your data?

Comment: Yes I want to apply some transformation before sending the data. Basically I have 7-8 table are in 1st RDS mysql instance and I want to transfer this data to other Mysql database which having 2-3 tables only. So I want to only transfer the data which is relevant to 2nd Mysql instance. Both the Mysql database are reside in same RDS instance.

Moreover If this is not possible to send the data between two mysql database then I will ready to merge both database tables to single database, but using the AWS glue ETL script the data should be transfer to respective table

Answer (score 2):

You can use pymysql or mysql.connector as a seperate zip file added to the glue job.  We have used pymysql for all our production jobs running in AWS Glue/Aurora RDS

Use this connectors to connect to both the RDS Mysql instances.  Read data from RDS Source db1 into a dataframe, perform the transformations, and finally write the transformed data to the RDS Target DB tables.

Here is the sample script for connecting to mysql connector, loading data from S3 into a staging table before loading to target database.

```
conn1 = mysql.connector.connect(host=url1, user=uname1, password=pwd1, database=sourcedbase)
cur1 = conn1.cursor()
cur1, conn1 = connect()

conn2 = mysql.connector.connect(host=url2, user=uname2, password=pwd2, database=targetdbase)
cur2 = conn2.cursor()
cur2, conn2 = connect()

createStgTable1 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mydb.STG_TABLE;"
createStgTable2 = "CREATE TABLE mydb.STG_TABLE(COL1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, COL2 VARCHAR(50), COL3 VARCHAR(50), COL4 CHAR(1) NOT NULL);"
loadQry = "LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 's3://<bucketname>/folder' REPLACE INTO TABLE mydb.STG_TABLE FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@var1, @var2, @var3, @var4) SET col1= @var1, col2= @var2, col3= @var3, col4=@var4;"
cur.execute(createStgTable1)
cur.execute(createStgTable2)
cur.execute(loadQry)
conn.commit()
```

**"Load data....."** is from Aurora, to load data from S3 directly into a mysql table.

**Insert query to RDS Instance:**

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=url, user=uname, password=pwd, database=dbase)
cur = conn.cursor()
insertQry = "INSERT INTO emp (id, emp_name, dept, designation, address1, city, state, active_start_date, is_active) SELECT (SELECT coalesce(MAX(ID),0) + 1 FROM atlas.emp) id, tmp.emp_name, tmp.dept, tmp.designation, tmp.address1, tmp.city, tmp.state, tmp.active_start_date, tmp.is_active from EMP_STG tmp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dept=tmp.dept, designation=tmp.designation, address1=tmp.address1, city=tmp.city, state=tmp.state, active_start_date=tmp.active_start_date, is_active =tmp.is_active ;"

n = cur.execute(insertQry)
print (" CURSOR status :", n)
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please provide the steps, I am new in AWS.

Comment: Anyway to load the data from S3 to mysql like Aurora? How to "LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX" with mysql, not aurora?

Answer (score 1):

For high level steps regarding the GLUE / Scripts:

1) Create a zip file for pymysql or mysql.connector.  Refer or google for the steps involved in this.

2) Upload your ETL python script for reading / writing between RDS, to an S3 location.  AWS Glue provides its own code generator, you can use if it suits the transformation your are looking at.

3) You need to create an AWS Glue job, configure the job by pointing to you uploaded ETL script, the mysql jar files, etc.  The rest you can leave it to default.

4) You also require certain IAM roles so that Glue can run the python script on your behalf.

[Please refer this AWS Document on Glue jobs for more details on configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job.html)

Comment: While creating the ETL job requires to choose a data source. How Can I add the data source. Please refer the below screenshot
http://prntscr.com/qirei9

Is it require to add "crawler"?

Comment: This is required if you are creating Glue Crawlers/Catalogs, and Glue JDBC connections, etc.  which I believe wouldn't be able to explain here, you can refer to Glue documents.  For the below approach, you can ignore by clicking NEXT button.

Comment: I think it depends upon the job configuration.  If you chose code generator, then its mandatory.  Please chose "An existing script that you provide" in the job configuration for the script sections.

Comment: thanks Now I am able to add the script but now its showing the errors while running the job

http://prntscr.com/qirzkq

Comment: Please go to the job history, click on LOGs / Error logs, and you would be able to see the cause of the error.